# Elasticsearch query + filter

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my original query dsl, and total of hits was 8,981.

```
GET /{index}/{document}/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "blue shoes",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "description": {
              "query": "blue shoes",
              "operator": "and",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add filter to this query.

```
GET /{index}/{document}/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "blue shoes",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "description": {
              "query": "blue shoes",
              "operator": "and",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "store.id": [ "store_a.com", "store_b.com" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now its total of hits is 15,989(`increased`).
And I sort the result by score in asc(I don't know why it's asc not desc), there are documents which is scored 0.

I think there is no more filtering by query because it is already filtered.

Can I remove 0 scored documents from the result?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did my answer help or did I miss something?

Comment: @nikoshr sorry for my late response. I solved this problem by just moving one of match(in this case 'title') from 'should' to 'must'.

Answer (score 0):

To add a filter, use a [`must` clause](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html#bool-filter) in your bool query to add a mandatory value. Try :

```
GET /{index}/{document}/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                "terms": {
                    "store.id": [ "store_a.com", "store_b.com" ]
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "title": {
                            "query": "blue shoes",
                            "boost": 2
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "description": {
                            "query": "blue shoes",
                            "operator": "and",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```